# Do I need to secure a form that is not connected to a database

Tags: php, html, regex, security

I have read about security issues when it comes to sql injections and so on.

I am not too familiar with security vulnerabilities in input fields.

I currently have a form that takes in inputs (the are validated through regex) for example an email validation would be the following:

```
if(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i.test(document.getElementById(idName).value)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

These values are not connected to the database and are only used in a php script. Are there any security vulnerabilities that I need to be aware of? Or by using regex validations I am safe against vulnerabilities?

Any information is much appreciated,

Thank you,
Al

Comment: Most security vulnerabilities (all?) that stem from user-input come from unsanitized data being used in certain ways; without knowing what you intended to use it for in PHP it's difficult to know what vulnerabilities you are facing.

Comment: Yes..even if the pages are not being used with Database, security is a concern with javascript type entries. Use regex expressions & htmlspecial entities in accepting inputs. Also clear your use of the page & take security issues as required.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @DevLakshman I am not familiar with terminology such as "clear your use of the page" can you elaborate?

Comment: Means for which level of security you want. It will be decided by the use or reason of the  created page e.g. pages created for increasing no. of users requires increased security & for lesser, less security. Hope you got it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You should definitely not rely on the client side validation through the javascript regex in case you are interested in having a valid email (at least valid against your regex) on the server side. Imagine somebody changing the client side code to the following (just one option of thousands :)):

```
if(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i.test(document.getElementById(idName).value)){
    return true;
}else{
    // CHANGED:
    return true;
}
```

And to generally answer your question: I think in almost all cases where you use input send by the client in your php code, you need a kind of input filtering/sanitazation but you cannot really generalize this task. That's why there is no generally valid sanitize() function out there since it always depends on how you use the input on the server side.

An approach in your case could be to validate the input again against the same regex via php or to use php's filter_var() in combination with the [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php) filter

**UPDATE**

I just found again a very nice article about input validation which helped me a lot: [Input validation](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Input-Validation.html)

Comment: Right now these inputs are being checked as a person is writing each input and then again when they click the submit button for the form. I use javascript in another php file that is called when an input changes (using the onchange function) and then the onsubmit function to check again when the submit button is clicked...Would this not be all I need from the client and backend perspective?

Comment: Well, as long as I understand you are not validating your input on the server side (by PHP) and it sounds like you are mixing up the client and server side but please tell when I'm wrong. Did you implement the validation only in javascript or do you have something on the server side (= PHP code). No matter how many times you validate via javascript since a user could just replace the whole javascript, or easier delete it

Comment: Currently what I am trying to accomplish is still in the making and not online. But from what I understand is since the javascript can be replaced/deleted I have to also create the same checks through only PHP code which protects the server side. So simply javascript on the client side and php for server side securities. So if someone were to change the javascript or delete I should have the same checks done in my php.